# Parse string with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string I need to parse. The problem is that some parts of the string is not always the same.

> a3:S8:[gmpage]S17:Head GM
>   NecrocideS12:test [15158]

The first 18 chars are always the same, so those can i `String.Substring()` out with ease.

My problem is that the characters `S12:` not always is `S12:`, it could easily be `S26:` - so i can not use a simple `String.Replace()` on it. I need to replace those 3 characters to `:&nbsp;`

How can I do that with regex? Thank you.

Comment: By S12, do you mean S17?

Comment: No there is something in the line NecrocideS12:test :-)

Comment: Oops, missed the S12 at the end of Necrocide because of the coloring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
string input = "a3:S8:[gmpage]S17:Head GM NecrocideS12:test [15158]";
string output = Regex.Replace(myString, "NecrocideS\d\d:", "Necrocide:");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\A(?<before>a3:S8:\[gmpage\])(?<delete>.{3})(?<after>:Head GM NecrocideS12:test \[15158\])\Z");
string input = @"a3:S8:[gmpage]S26:Head GM NecrocideS12:test [15158]";
string output = reg.Replace(input, "${before}${after}");
```

This will replace S26 by ""