# How to parse float values from string using REGEX in java

Tags: java, android, regex, parsing

I want to parse float values from

```
CallCost:Rs.13.04 Duration:00:00:02 Bal:Rs.14.67 2016 mein Promotion
```

From above string i need 13.04 and 14.67. I used following regex

```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d*\\.\\d+");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
  while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(">> " + m.group());
            }
```

But using this i am getting ".13", ".04", ".14", ".67"
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse string with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646484/parse-string-with-regex)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\\d+` instead of `\\d*`

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+");
```

Why?

Because if you use `\\d*\\.\\d+`, this should match from the dot exists next to `Rs`, since you made the integer part to repeat zero or more times., So it don't care about the integer part.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yR0lI4/1)

Comment: See also, the differences between Java regex quantifiers, as documented in the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: It works fine but can i split this string on behalf of float values ex. CallCost:Rs.13.04 Duration:00:00:02 Bal:Rs.14.67 2016 mein Promotion into["CallCost:Rs.13.04 ","Duration:00:00:02 Bal:Rs.14.67"]

Comment: Yes my next action is this

Comment: thanks bro...its working perfect..Can you please suggest me any website or tutorials to get regex correspond to requirements.

Comment: Nice Answer . Happy coding