# How to parse particular string from a given string using REGEX

Tags: java, regex, parsing

```
Mobile Internet 50MB Balance 30.1MB till Jan 12,2016 11:59:59 PM.
```

I have this response of internet balance deduction and i want to parse this string on behalf of MB. I used this regex expression;
`\\MB?` but it includes "M" and "MB" both at a time. I also used this link
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34290463/how-to-parse-float-values-from-string-using-regex-in-java)
 but was not able to get. Don't know where i am getting stuck. Any suggession will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you need to use positive lookahead.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?=MB?)");
```

If you don't want to make B optional then try this,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?=MB)");
```

Click the link below for a running demo.

- `\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?` would match all the numbers (*integers as well as floating point numbers since I made the decimal part as optional*)
- `(?=MB)` Asserts that the match must be followed by `MB`. So this would match all the numbers which exists immediately before `MB`.

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/wV6jB1/1)

Comment: thnk u so mch @Avinash Raj